# Does Yuu Otosaka remember everyone at the end of episode 13?

Tags: charlotte

At the end of episode 13, Yuu is shown to reunite with Takajo, Yusa, Ayumi, and Nao. Does he actually remember them or did he use one of his abilities to regain his memory?

Comment: i think no, maybe he was waiting too see everything in his past memory in the nao camera and he is looking toward to it (sorry for bad explain)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Sadly, he does not.

From the [Charlotte Wikia](http://charlotte-anime.wikia.com/wiki/Y%C5%AB_Otosaka):

> "Plunder" has a side effect. The more people he loots abilities from, the more memories he loses.

After absorbing tens of thousands of different abilities from people around the world he lost all of his memories.

[image: When Otosaka Yuu first wakes up]

The only thing he knows is how precious the phrasebook was to him during his journey, thus why he could never get rid of it.

The title of the episode itself, *Memories to Come*, foreshadows the idea that he will now be living for the memories he's yet to create. At the end of the episode he's reunited with the student council and his sister but is lost for what he should say because he doesn't share the same memories as them.

[image: Yuu lost for words]

And with that, the foreshadowing from the episode title is underlined with when Takajou prompts him to be honest and Yuu responds with, "I'm looking forward to what's to come."

[image: I'm looking forward to what's to come.]

Comment: That explains alot. Thanks for providing your insight, it really helped me understand the ending now.

Comment: Loved this answer :)

Comment: Oh hey look, another Yuu that becomes disabled doe to saving the world. Those shonen protagonists these days, they be no longer over 9000, it seems